# Name of 2D Image From Above

Tags: terminology, art, perspective

What do you call a 2D game where its view is directly from above looking down?

Does the art style have a similar name? (Ie isometric is a art style, but not the art style name I am after.)

When I use "top down", people do not seem to understand what I mean.

Comment: It sounds like you're describing a top down or overhead *perspective*; similarly, isometric is a perspective that can be used by various styles. If "top-down" or "overhead" is not effectively communicating what you mean, please edit to include an image that shows the view &/or style that you are trying to name / describe.

Comment: The artist understood "overhead". So thanks for that.

Comment: ["Isometric" is not an art style, it's a projection technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection). You can draw in many different styles with the same projection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're describing a *top down* or *overhead perspective*; similarly, isometric is a perspective that can be used by various styles.

The projection may also be a consideration and might be the source of some confusion. For example consider the following screenshots.

Hotline Miami:
[image: Hotline Miami screenshot]

Ape Out:
[image: Ape Out screenshot]

Both games use an overhead view. Hotline Miami has a parallel projection and uses pixel art. Ape out has a perspective projection and uses low res 3D modelled art.

Since some combination tend to be found together often, sometimes terms get used confused. If you're having trouble communicating what you mean to your artist verbally, include some examples.

Comment: Thanks. What I am after is like the Miami game, but a different setting. I also want the pixel art style. So, "top-down", "overhead", "pixel-art" is a good way to describe what I am after.

Answer (score 1):

Top down would be the right way to describe it but you could give examples like Diablo 2 or ragnarok online to get them to understand better.

Comment: I agree with you that top-down is the correct term, but the games you cited as examples are not top-down view games. As mentioned in the question, they are looking for something where its view is looking down directly from above.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Ktystal-Fong . I think I will be describing what I am after is a "top-down", "overhead", "pixel-art".